# What is the meaning of these criticisms of Aristotelian logic?

Tags: logic, aristotle, wittgenstein, bertrand-russell

I'm reading Ray Monk's biography of Wittgenstein and, on a scathing book review of Wittgenstein's, Monk writes,

> There follows a list of such mistakes, which are, for the most part
>   the weaknesses of traditional (Aristotelian) logic customarily 
>   pointed out by adherents of Russellian mathematical logic - for instance,
>   that it assumes the copula 'is' (as in 'Socrates is mortal') with the
>   'is' of identity ('Twice two is four'), and so on.

I was wondering if somebody could explain these criticisms to somebody who has never studied philosophy?

Comment: See also the related post: [Wittgenstein criticizes Coffey's work *The science of logic*](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30848/wittgenstein-criticizes-coffeys-work-the-science-of-logic-in-its-assumption-t)

Comment: J, Hintikka has strongly opposed the received view about the differences in use of 'is' and even said plainly that it is wrong. Two of his papers: (1984) * Semantical games, the alleged ambiguity of ‘is’, and Aristotelian categories*,  Synthese, vol. 54, p. 443–68; (1979) * “Is”, semantical games, and semantical relativity*,  J. of Phph. Logic, vol 8,  p.433–68.

Answer (score 2):

"is" in modern logic has different translations, according to the context:

*(i)* *identity*: "Socrates *is* the teacher of Plato".

*(ii)* *membership*: "Socrates *is* mortal", that means that the individual Socrates belongs to the set (or class) of mortals.

*(iii)* *inclusion*: "French *are* Europeans", that means that the set (or class) of French is included into (is a subset of) the set of Europeans.

---

[Aristotelian Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#PreStrAss) (based on the *syllogism*) is based on the grammatical relation of *predication*: *Socrates is human, Plato is not a horse, horses are animals, humans are not horses*:

> One major difference between Aristotle’s understanding of predication and modern logic is that Aristotle treats individual predications and general predications as similar in logical form: he gives the same analysis to “Socrates is an animal” and “Humans are animals”.

Comment: Why do you say "grammatical relation" and simply not, e.g., "logical relation"?

Comment: This strikes me as more or less right, although it's worth emphasizing that what distinguishes (i) - (iii) is that distinct expression types flank 'is' in each case: singular terms in (i); a singular term and a predicate in (ii); and two predicates in (iii).